# Add notification to RoR messaging inbox system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications, messaging, inbox

I have a rails app with intern messaging system. User can send message to other user. Example : User 1 send message User 2 can respond viceversa.

All works perfectly. But I want to upgrade this system with notfications functionnality. I want to type of notifications :

1) On navbar
2) By mail

Problem : I dont know how i can do this.

Can you help me ?

Conversations table

```
class CreateConversations < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :conversations do |t|
   t.integer :sender_id
   t.integer :recipient_id
   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

Messages table. In this code I have a boolean :read. I think solution can be here. What do you think about this ?

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :messages do |t|
   t.text :body
   t.references :conversation, index: true
   t.references :user, index: true
   t.boolean :read, :default => false
   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

conversation.rb

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
 belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'
has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, :scope => :recipient_id
scope :between, -> (sender_id,recipient_id) do
 where("(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?)", sender_id,recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
 end
end
```

Message.rb

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :conversation
 belongs_to :user
 validates_presence_of :body, :conversation_id, :user_id
 def message_time
  created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%y at %l:%M %p")
 end
end
```

conversations_controller.rb

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /conversations
  # GET /conversations.json
  def index
    @users = User.all

    # Restrict to conversations with at least one message and sort by last updated
    @conversations = Conversation.joins(:messages).uniq.order('updated_at DESC')
  end

  # POST /conversations
  # POST /conversations.json
  def create
  if Conversation.between(params[:conversation][:sender_id], params[:conversation][:recipient_id]).present?
    @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:conversation][:sender_id], params[:conversation][:recipient_id]).first
  else
    @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
  end

  redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def conversation_params
      params.require(:conversation).permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id)
    end
end
```

messages_controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action do
   @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
  end
def index
 @messages = @conversation.messages
  if @messages.length > 10
   @over_ten = true
   @messages = @messages[-10..-1]
  end
  if params[:m]
   @over_ten = false
   @messages = @conversation.messages
  end
 if @messages.last
  if @messages.last.user_id != current_user.id
   @messages.last.read = true;
  end
 end
@message = @conversation.messages.new
 end
def new
 @message = @conversation.messages.new
end
def create
 @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
 if @message.save
  redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
 end
end
private
 def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:body, :user_id)
 end
end
```

/conversations/index.html.erb

```
<div class="ui segment">
 <h3>Mailbox</h3>
 <div class="ui list">
  <div class="item">
   <% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
   <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id || conversation.recipient_id == current_user.id %>
    <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id %>
      <% recipient = User.find(conversation.recipient_id) %>
    <% else %>
      <% recipient = User.find(conversation.sender_id) %>
    <% end %>
    Conversation avec <%= link_to recipient.prenom,   conversation_messages_path(conversation)%>
   <% end %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="ui segment">
 <h3>All Users</h3>
  <div class="ui list">
   <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <% if user.id != current_user.id %>
     <div class="item">
   <%= user.prenom %> <%= button_to 'Message me', conversations_path(conversation: { sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: user.id }), class: 'btn btn-primary m-t' %>
 </div>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

messages/index.html.erb

```
<% if @over_ten %>
 <%= link_to 'Show Previous', "?m=all" %>
<% end %>
<div class="ui segment">
 <% @messages.each do |message| %>
  <% if message.body %>
   <% user = User.find(message.user_id) %>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="content">
     <div class="header"><strong><div class="imageavatarmessage"><%= image_tag user.avatar(:thumb), class:"imageavatarmessage" %></div><%= user.prenom %></strong>     <%= message.message_time %></div>
      <div class="list">
       <div class="item">
        <i class="right triangle icon"></i>
         <%= message.body %>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
<%= form_for [@conversation, @message], html: {class: "ui reply form"} do |f| %>
 <div class=”field”>
   <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control" %>
 </div>
 <%= f.text_field :user_id, value: current_user.id, type: "hidden" %>
 <div>
   <%= f.submit "Add Reply", class: "ui blue labeled submit icon button" %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to go through this tutorial to build nice notification system
https://www.devwalks.com/lets-build-instagram-part-6-notifications/

Basically, you have to create new model, set dependencies with your `Message` model and integrate to the controller

For the email notifications, it's even simpler. 
Just create new mailer and fire it on create action in `messages_controller`

```
def create
 @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
 if @message.save
  SendMessageMailer.new_message(@message).deliver_later
  redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
 end
end
```

**EDIT:** 
To create mailer, you should do something like this:

```
rails g mailer SendMessage
```

Go to /app/mailers/send_message_mailer.rb and add action, same type of building as controllers

```
def new_message(message)
    @message = message
    mail(to: @message.user.email, subject: 'Hey! Here is what you missed')
end
```

Also, create an view (email template) and code with erb code

```
app/views/send_message_mailer/new_message.html.erb
```

Im not going deep into this, I guess you can figure out how to pass interval (let's say don't send if user is online or have read the message) and differentiate with receiver/sender users

Mailer, once again, is just same type of controller. You can pass as many params as you need and use model nesting inside mailer controller and views

mailer

```
def new_message(message, sender, receiver)
end
```

controller

```
SendMessageMailer.new_message(@message, @message.user, params[:receiver]).deliver_later
```

Comment: hey @sergey-khmelevskoy Thanks for this link and for this comment. Mailer is just simple like this ?

Comment: Pretty much it is. And as always, official guide is an good reference.http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html