# Rails Action Mailer - Create email notification to recipient of message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm working on a Rails 5 Marketplace App and have a chat feature where users can message eachother. I'm trying to create a new Mailer to send to the recipient of a message when they're offline. Tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40431718/add-notification-to-ror-messaging-inbox-system) but kept running into problems.

user.rb model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :conversations, :foreign_key => :sender_id
```

conversation model

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'

has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, :scope => :recipient_id

scope :between, -> (sender_id,recipient_id) do
  where("(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?)", sender_id,recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
  end
end
```

Message Model

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :body, :conversation_id, :user_id

  def message_time
    created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%y at %l:%M %p")
  end

  
end
```

Messages Controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    before_action do
      @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
    end
  
    def index
      @messages = @conversation.messages
      if @messages.length > 10
        @over_ten = true
        @messages = @messages[-10..-1]
      end
      if params[:m]
        @over_ten = false
        @messages = @conversation.messages
      end
      if @messages.last
        if @messages.last.user_id != current_user.id
          @messages.last.read = true;
        end
      end
  
      @message = @conversation.messages.new
    end
  
    def new
      @message = @conversation.messages.new
    end
  
    def create
      @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
      if @message.save
        SendMessageMailer.new_message(@message.user, params[:recipient_id]).deliver_later
        redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
      end
    end
  
  private
    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:body, :user_id)
    end
  end
```

Send Message Mailer

```
class SendMessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: 'peter@toolsof.golf'
   
    def new_message(message, recipient_id)
        @message = message
        mail(to: @message.email, subject: 'You have a new message')
    end
  end
```

It keeps sending email to the sender of the message, not the recipient. I would like to send to the recipient.

NEW VERSION

Message Controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    before_action do
      @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
    end
  
    def index
      @messages = @conversation.messages
      if @messages.length > 10
        @over_ten = true
        @messages = @messages[-10..-1]
      end
      if params[:m]
        @over_ten = false
        @messages = @conversation.messages
      end
      if @messages.last
        if @messages.last.user_id != current_user.id
          @messages.last.read = true;
        end
      end
  
      @message = @conversation.messages.new
    end
  
    def new
      @message = @conversation.messages.new
    end
  
    def create
      @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
      @receiver = @conversation.recipient_id
      if @message.save
        SendMessageMailer.new_message(@message,  @receiver ).deliver
        redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
      end
    end
  
  private
    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:body, :user_id, :sender_id, :recipient_id)
    end
  end
```

Send Message Mailer

```
class SendMessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: 'peter@toolsof.golf'
   
    def new_message(message, receiver)
        @receiver = receiver
        mail(to: @receiver.email, subject: 'You have a new message')
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
class SendMessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: 'peter@toolsof.golf'
   
    def new_message(message, recipient_id)
        @message = message
        mail(to: @message.email, subject: 'You have a new message')
    end
  end
```

try

```
class SendMessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: 'peter@toolsof.golf'
   
    def new_message(message, recipient_id)
        @recipient = User.find(recipient_id)
        mail(to: @recipient.email, subject: 'You have a new message')
    end
  end
```

Your current new_message method is sending the email to @message.user.email, which is the email address for the sender of the email not the recipient.

If you also need the message body for your email, you'll need to change:

```
SendMessageMailer.new_message(@message.user, params[:recipient_id]).deliver_later
```

to

```
SendMessageMailer.new_message(@message, params[:recipient_id]).deliver_later
```

so that you can access the @message.body inside your message mailer.

For more information, see the [action mailer guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

UPDATED BASED ON NEW VERSION

```
@receiver = @conversation.recipient_id
```

is just a number (the recipient_id) so you can't call @receiver.email on it. You still need to lookup the User associated with the recipient_id at some point in the process:

```
@recipient = User.find(recipient_id)
```

Comment: thank you for this! I got an error message that says 'couldn't find a user without an ID. Do I need to add :recipient_id to my user model?

```has_many :messages, :foreign_key => :recipient_id```

Comment: I don't think it would make sense to add it to the user. Given what you currently have, you should be able to access it as @conversation.recipient_id in your messages controller and pass that to your mailer. It may also be available in your params object, but you'd have to check how that is structured. I can't tell what your params might contain, but  params[:recipient_id] doesn't appear to be correct.

Comment: I added a new version in my original question - is this closer to the right track? I'm confused how to pass through the recipient id properly

Comment: see new information add to my original answer.

Comment: thank you @cadair, looks like it's working but I'm now receiving an SMTP error (to confirm, Ive tested my other Mailer and it still works for me).

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 279ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)

Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
):

Comment: Are both emails being sent from the same email account (peter@tooslof.golf)?  If so, it may be an issue with your actionmailer config.

Answer (score 0):

@cadair thank you for your help. I was able to get the following to work:

mailer

```
class SendMessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: 'peter@example.com'
   
    def new_message(message, userSender, userReceiver)
        @recipient =  userReceiver
        @sender = userSender
        @message = message
        mail(to: @recipient.email, subject: 'You have a new message')
    end
  end
```

Messages Controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    before_action do
      @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
    end
  
    def index
      @messages = @conversation.messages
      if @messages.length > 10
        @over_ten = true
        @messages = @messages[-10..-1]
      end
      if params[:m]
        @over_ten = false
        @messages = @conversation.messages
      end
      if @messages.last
        if @messages.last.user_id != current_user.id
          @messages.last.read = true;
        end
      end
  
      @message = @conversation.messages.new
    end
  
    def new
      @message = @conversation.messages.new
    end
  
    def create
      @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
      userReceiver = User.find(@conversation.recipient_id)
      userSender = User.find(@conversation.sender_id)
      
      if @message.save
        SendMessageMailer.new_message(@message, userSender,  userReceiver ).deliver_later
        redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
      end
    end
  
  private
    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:body, :user_id, :sender_id, :recipient_id)
    end
  end
```

mymailer.html.erb

```
<h1> New Message </h1>

<p>hello @<%= @recipient.name%> , you've received a new message from @<%= @sender.name %> .</p>


<p> <%= @message.body %></p>
```